# Vertical center with flexbox not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox within a bootstrap grid to make a thin menu with items vertically centered but it isn't working. I've attempted to use the styles presented in [this demo](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/), but apparently i've still got something incorrect.

#### Markup

```
  <section class="container secondary-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <nav class="secondary-header__nav">
          <ul class="secondary-nav__list-items">
            <li class="secondary-nav__list-item">
              <a class="secondary-nav__link">Option</a>
            </li>
            <li class="secondary-nav__list-item">
              <a class="secondary-nav__link">Option</a>
            </li>
            <li class="secondary-nav__list-item">
              <a class="secondary-nav__link">Option</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

#### SCSS

```
.secondary-header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2bf;
}
.secondary-nav {

  &__list-items {
    display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;    

  }  

  &__nav {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
  }

  &__list-items {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  &__list-item {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;    
    // height: 60px;
  }

  &__list-item {
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `.secondary-nav__list-items` is your flex-parent, but it's height doesn't consume the height of `.secondary-header` which has the blue background, and is where you want the items within `.secondary-nav__list-items` to be centered.

You could either make sure everything between `.secondary-header` and `.secondary-nav__list-items` has height 100%, so that `.secondary-nav__list-items` will be as tall as `.secondary-header`, or just move the height/background to `.secondary-nav__list-items` instead.

```css
.secondary-nav__list-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.secondary-nav__nav {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
}
.secondary-nav__list-items {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2bf;
}
.secondary-nav__list-item {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.secondary-nav__list-item {
  display: inline;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="container secondary-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <nav class="secondary-header__nav">
          <ul class="secondary-nav__list-items">
            <li class="secondary-nav__list-item">
              <a class="secondary-nav__link">Option</a>
            </li>
            <li class="secondary-nav__list-item">
              <a class="secondary-nav__link">Option</a>
            </li>
            <li class="secondary-nav__list-item">
              <a class="secondary-nav__link">Option</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>        
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```